# Simple way to send debug information to the Visual Studio 'Output' window

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, output-window, debug-information

I started a blank project in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) to write a C application. How can I send debug information to the *Output* window (menu *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Output* )? Is there a relatively simple way to implement `TRACE` or `OutputDebugString` or something similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing output on the Output Window in Visual C++ IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697842/printing-output-on-the-output-window-in-visual-c-ide)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1333527/39648

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is *the* way to do it. Stack Overflow question *[How can I use the TRACE macro in non-MFC projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494653)* contains information how to make something akin to [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library)'s [`TRACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w95a4ha%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) macro using `OutputDebugString`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `OutputDebugString` from a VS C program.

```
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("Hello World\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

The output will only be visible if you run with debugging (Debug > Start Debugging)

In the Output window, select "Debug" for "Show output from:"

Comment: @Simon it's a standard Microsoft pre-processor macro for dealing with creating programs that compile both in Unicode mode and ANSI mode.  You can remove the _T() if you're not using [tchar.h and friends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx#tchars).

Answer (score 3):

If you use C++, you may be interested on my portable TRACE macro.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_TRACE
#  ifdef _MSC_VER
#    include <windows.h>
#    include <sstream>
#    define TRACE(x)                           \
     do {  std::ostringstream s;  s << x;      \
           OutputDebugString(s.str().c_str()); \
        } while(0)
#  else
#    include <iostream>
#    define TRACE(x)  std::cerr << x << std::flush
#  endif
#else
#  define TRACE(x)
#endif
```

example:

```
#define ENABLE_TRACE  //can depend on _DEBUG or NDEBUG macros
#include "my_above_trace_header.h"

int main (void)
{
   int     i = 123;
   double  d = 456.789;
   TRACE ("main() i="<< i <<" d="<< d <<'\n');
}
```

Any improvements/suggestions/contributions are welcome ;-)