# Output to console/Debug window in Win32 Application on MVC++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express: In a C++ WinAPI application, how do I print to the debug window? What function do I use?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing output on the Output Window in Visual C++ IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697842/printing-output-on-the-output-window-in-visual-c-ide)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`OutputDebugString` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx).

When running under the debugger (e.g., in Visual Studio), the arguments to this function are automatically redirected to the Output window.